# Excel crashes when renewing auto-filters oncellchange

Tags: excel, crash, autofilter, vba

I use the following code to refresh an autofilter in Excel upon a cell change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
  'On Error Resume Next
  'Set MySheet = Application.ActiveSheet
  'MySheet.Columns(1).AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
  'On Error Resume Next
  'Application.EnableEvents = False
  Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Range("$A$1:$A$146").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("0", _
        "2", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
  'Application.EnableEvents = True
  'On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I use this to hide rows based on certain criteria.
And for that it works really well.

**The problem**
However when I set validation on a cell and add one of those cool dropdown lists.
[image]
To get the cell to look like this:
[image]

That part works fine, but as soon as I choose a different value that causes the autofilter to hide/display different cells **excel crashes**

**My theory**
The validation drop down changes a cell.
This triggers the VBA code shown above.
However the validation code is still running, whilst the filter settings get reinitialized.
This causes Excel to crash.

**How do I fix this?**
Will running the VBA event delayed somehow help?
How do I do that?

Comment: Created a new excel sheet (in 2010) and pasting your code in does not make excel crash for me. You need to provide more info on what data is in what column and what cell you are adding validation to or even better point us to a copy of your sheet we can look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a racing condition, if the filter is reapplied **before** calculation has finished it will make Excel crash.
This does require a large sheet so that calculation takes long enough for this to occur.

Here's the work around:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ReapplyFilter As Boolean

'OnCalculate is always called twice, before and after calculation.
'I'm only interested in the event after.  
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  If (Application.CalculationState = xlDone) And (ReapplyFilter = True) Then
    ReapplyFilter = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Range("$A$1:$A$146").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("0", _
          "2", "3", "4", "5", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    On Error GoTo 0
  End If

End Sub

'Always Reapply the filter on activation of the sheet.
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Worksheets("Basisgegevens").Range("$A$1:$A$146").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("0", _
          "2", "3", "4", "5", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub

'OnChange: set the flag to be picked up by calculation later on.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
  ReapplyFilter = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with what you are doing now. But I suspect there is another component causing this crash such as addins. Why don't you unload or delete unnecessary addins ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/load-or-unload-add-in-programs-HP010096834.aspx) and try the code again?

Comment: It's not addins, I've found a workaround that solves this problem. See my answer below.